# Do I need to delete/free dynamically allocated data (e.g. bytearray or std::vector) within a std::deque before I can call pop_back?

Tags: arrays, dynamic, stdvector, allocation, stddeque

As far as I understand push_back() of std::deque copies the data I put in. So, when I put in  reference to dynamic data (such as to a dynamic bytearray or std::vector) it copies only the reference to it. Now I try to understand if I have to delete/free my dynamically allocated data before pop_back() from std::deque? C++11 is given. Hope someone can help me out! Below I have my two scenarios in as code examples:

Scenario I:

---

```
  typedef struct mystruct{
    uint8_t* data; 
    //other fields may be here
  } mystruct_t;

  mystruct_t my;
  my.data = new uint8_t[3];
  my.data[0] = 'A';
  my.data[1] = 'B';
  my.data[2] = 'C';
  std::deque<mystruct_t> d;
  d.push_back(my);
  // ...
  // Need to delete/free data here, before d.pop_back()?
  d.pop_back();
```

---

Scenario II:

---

```
  typedef struct mystruct{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
    // other fields may be here
  } mystruct_t;

  mystruct_t my;
  my.data.push_back('A');
  my.data.push_back('B');
  my.data.push_back('C');

  std::deque<mystruct_t> d;
  d.push_back(my);
  // ...
  // Need to delete/free data here, before d.pop_back()?
  d.pop_back();
```

---

Comment: You know you don't need to use `typedef` with structures in C++? Also IIRC types ending with the name `_t` are reserved.

Comment: Nope, thought is the better way to do it, thanks for the hint! Just getting in closer touch with C++! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, because no one was answering, I try to answer myself considering new findings:

I made some runtime tests of the code shown above in an endless loop while putting 1 MB of data in the bytearray / vector with / without freeing it and monitored system memory behavior while running.

Testing scenario I:

---

```
struct mystruct{
  uint8_t* data; 
  //other fields may be here
};

int j = 0;
while(1){

  j++;

  mystruct my;
  my.data = new uint8_t[1000000]; // approx. 1 MB
  for(int i=0;i<=1000000;i++){
    my.data[i] = 'A';
  }      
  std::deque<mystruct> d;
  d.push_back(my);
  // TBD: Need to delete/free data here, before d.pop_back()?
  // delete[] d[0].data;
  d.pop_back();

  Log(LogLevel::kInfo) << "pushing and popping ... " << j;

}
```

---

Testing scenario II:

---

```
  typedef struct mystruct{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
    // other fields may be here
  } mystruct_t;

  std::deque<mystruct_t> d;

    int j = 0;
    while(1){

      j++;

      mystruct my;      
      for(int i=0;i<=1000000;i++){  // approx. 1 MB
        my.data.push_back('A');
      }      
      std::deque<mystruct> d;
      d.push_back(my);

      // TBD: Need to delete/free data here, before d.pop_back()?      
      //  for(int i=0;i<=1000000;i++){  // approx. 1 MB
      //    d[0].data.pop_back();
      //  }  

      d.pop_back();

      Log(LogLevel::kInfo) << "pushing and popping ... " << j;

    }
```

---

The results are:

- Scenario I increases used memory a lot and crashes shortily after start when the bytearray is not deleted. If the byte array is deleted in each iteration, all works stable.
- In Scenario II the memory usage keeps stable, even without popping elements from the vector<>. So, it seems this is done somehow internally. Scenario II with popping each element from the vector, before popping the deque was stable as well.

Additional remarks: Scenario II was much slower than Scenario I, especially when all the elements in the vector are popped each time.

Would be happy if someone could explain why the memory allocated by the vector seems to be freed when the hosting deque-element is popped.